# Strange Notepad.exe module dependency: Cryptbase.dll

Tags: windows-7, windows, virus

Running `tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq Untitled - Notepad" /M` on my friend's computer got me the following.

I was surprised that a simple program such as Notepad would have all those dependencies; but then almost all programs rely on Windows's libraries such as Kernel32.dll and user32.dll. That notwithstanding, I am doubtful that Notepad needs **CRYPTBASE.dll**

Any idea what it is? Is the computer compromised?

```
Image Name                     PID Modules
========================= ======== ============================================
notepad.exe                   5604 ntdll.dll, kernel32.dll, KERNELBASE.dll,
                                   ADVAPI32.dll, msvcrt.dll, sechost.dll,
                                   RPCRT4.dll, GDI32.dll, USER32.dll, LPK.dll,
                                   USP10.dll, COMDLG32.dll, SHLWAPI.dll,
                                   COMCTL32.dll, SHELL32.dll, WINSPOOL.DRV,
                                   ole32.dll, OLEAUT32.dll, VERSION.dll,
                                   IMM32.DLL, MSCTF.dll, CRYPTBASE.dll,
                                   uxtheme.dll, dwmapi.dll
```

Thank you for any ideas

Comment: The computer is fine, cryptbase.dll is installed with windows. It appears that windows explorer extensions are loading into notepad. Likely to be used by the open dialogue when opening files on a bitlocker encrypted partition.

Comment: this is the Base cryptographic API DLL. This is a legit Windows DLL

Comment: When I ran the same command on another computer, the CryptBase.dll didn't show as a notepad.exe dependency which increased my worries. But now I understand from your comments that the DLL is legit and is conditionally loaded (in case there is a need to deal with something encrypted). Thank you both so much; feel free to post your comment as answers

Comment: on windows 8 I see the DLL also loaded for notepad.

Comment: On Windows 10, I found bcrypt.dll and bcryptprimitives.dll but not cryptbase.dll